# Access one SFDC org via token retrieved from another org

Tags: salesforce, single-sign-on, jwt, access-token, openid-connect

I have 2 salesforce orgs that I need to access via API from my Single page application.
The first org should work as my IDP, to authenticate my user (I am planning to use user-agent flow).
When I authenticate to my IDP org, I am getting an access token and an OpenID token. How can I use any of them to access the second org (also via API)?

Answer (score 0):

So far it seems that I can use the ID token from the IDP to get an access token from the SP using the JWT bearer flow. Then use the access token from there onward.
But so far not sure if the ID token itself can be used instead of the access token to invoke the REST API in the SP. I have posted another question about this:
[Can I authenticate to and use REST API using an ID token](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48501839/can-i-authenticate-to-and-use-rest-api-using-an-id-token)